# phpldapadmin & 389 Directory Server: Password field not visible

Tags: ldap, phpldapadmin

I have a **389 Directory Server** cluster as ldap. I want use **phpldapadmin** as frontend.

All seems be good but when I login me with non admin user I can't see mi own password field even if user was created using **phpldapadmin**. Login works but i can change password value.

Same phpldapadmin configuration works fine with **openldap**.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a security feature probably implemented by a default ACI.  By default nobody except administrative users can read the userPassword attribute of user objects. The reason is quite simple: though hashing a password with something like MD5 or SSHA helps to protect it against attacks, this method isn't completely invulnerable to attack.  If someone gets a hold of your hash they could use [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) or a [password cracking rig](http://gizmodo.com/5966169/the-hardware-hackers-use-to-crack-your-passwords) to look-up / crack the hash and get the plain text password.  If you want a non-administrative user to have access to all user passwords you can add the following ACI to the proper object/container (probably ou=People):

```
aci: (targetattr = "userPassword") (version 3.0;acl "Password Reading";allow
  (read)(userdn = "ldap:///uid=SomeUser,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com");)
```

I would also advise you to use the 389 administration console over phpldapadmin as it provides a much richer interface for the features specific to 389.